# How to require an image with react electron outside of src folder(Application Support)

Tags: reactjs, image, electron

I want to require images dynamically from the Application Support folder. I use the react-app-rewired package to require outside of the src folder but when I use a window variable in the image src I get the error: Error: Cannot find module. I get the path like this and get an error code with a string that works when I use it directly in the src part of the image tag.

```
window.path = window.electron.remote.app.getPath("appData")
```

image(Does not work):

```
<img className="topSvg" src={require(""+window.path+'/current/'+this.props.project+'/src/content/img/changeable/'+data.top.img)} alt="top_svg"/>
```

`Error: Cannot find module '/Users/tobi/Library/Application Support/template-editor/current/Tobi/src/content/img/changeable/top_svg.svg`'

image(works):

```
<img className="topSvg" src={require('/Users/tobi/Library/Application Support/template-editor/current/Tobi/src/content/img/changeable/top_svg.svg')} alt="top_svg"/>
```

I also tried to just replace the window.path with the string '/Users/tobi/Library/Application Support/template-editor' which also works fine

Answer (score 0):

```
switch(process.platform) {

    case 'darwin': {
      return path.join(process.env.HOME, 'Library', 'Application Support', 'template-editor', ...);
    }
    case 'win32': {
      return path.join(process.env.APPDATA, 'template-editor', ...);
    }
    case 'linux': {
      return path.join(process.env.HOME, '.template-editor', ...);
    }
}
```

And if you are going to get the location of your app then use this
`process.env.PORTABLE_EXECUTABLE_DIR` But this variable will be only available when you used electron-builder to pack your app.

Comment: I tried to use process.ENV.HOME but it didn`t find HOME but window.process.env.HOME worked but I still got the same error then before

Comment: @TobiasBauer Sorry my typos. Yes I meant the env.HOME

Comment: Which error are you facing now? This error? <Can't find the module> ?

Comment: Use file:// to access the file from your local storage.
So **file://${appDataPath}/${filename}** like this. Then you should disable the websecurity in dev mode

Comment: Don't forget to enable the websecurity in prod mode

Comment: I now have this src: src={require("file://" + window.process.env.HOME + "/Library/Application Support"+'/template-editor/current/'+this.props.project+'/src/content/img/changeable/'+data.top.img)} but also this error: Module not found: Can't resolve 'file:/' in '/Users/tobi/Local Documents/template-editor/src/content/components'

Comment: Where is your code? If this is open source then let me meet that

Comment: try set like this

`src=\`/${window.process.env.HOME}/Library/Application\ Support/template-editor/current/${this.props.project}/src/content/img/changeable/${data.top.img}\``

Comment: But first of all, you must sure if the target file is exist at that path
Using console.log to check if this fullpath is correct

Comment: I know that it is correct because it works when I use a string like I described in my question above

Comment: I tried your code from the comment above but I have to use brackets and require and then get the same error like before

Comment: I think it's a very weird bug with the window variable because every time I use the path given in the error message it works but with variables, it doesn't work also when I replace the window.process.env.HOME or window.path with /Users/tobi as a String it works what is very weird.